# How can I use excel to find the offset of the max value in a range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working in excel and want the value of one cell to equal the offset of -1 columns to whatever value in a range is the largest.

Here is what I have so far.

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(D9:D11,MATCH(MAX(D9:D11),D9:D11,0)))
```

I thought it might be possible to set the value using VBA on change but, was not sure how to do that one either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close but I think is simpler:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(MAX(D:D),D:D,0))
```

Will only find the first instance (lowest row number) where the maximum is repeated.

The above is 'generalised' but for a specific range (say to avoid where a maximum value occurs more than once), something like:

```
=INDEX(C9:C11,MATCH(MAX(D9:D11),D9:D11,0))
```

[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) returns the position (if found, of the first instance) counting from the start of the range (so `1` if in D9 in the second example above). [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) also counts from the start of its range.

Comment: Would I be able to use something similar to what youre saying if I didnt want the max of the whole column but rather the offset of a range? such as D9:D11 in my example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Index formula mentioned above but you may want to generalize the formula to use all rows in column C and D (using C:C instead of C9:C11).

Another option is the "offset" formula below. Assuming the range you are "scanning" for the largest value is in column D, the formula would be:
=OFFSET(D1,MATCH(MAX(D:D),D:D)-1,-1)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an ID or a number for all values youre working on.
then, use other ID#2 which a sum of ID & the value. Then you implement maxif to ID#2. After that you use VLOOKUP to whatever data you want. no need to use OFFSET.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gtu9k.png)